# How to move cancel button in QProgressDialog to the center?

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressdialog

I want to move the Cancel button of `QProgressDialog` to the center; by default its on the left.

Below is a simple example, but I don't know how to change the button position.

```
_progress = new QProgressDialog();
_progress->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
_progress->setWindowTitle(tr("Stimulated Movement"));
_progress->setLabelText(tr("Please wait for a moment while the motor is moving!"));
_progress->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
_progress->setModal(true);
//make it Keep rolling
_progress->setRange(0, 0);
_progress->setCancelButton(new QPushButton(tr("Terminate")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) said:

> You have access to the QPushButton for the cancel, what's stopping you from simply moving it where you want when the dialog is shown?

Here's how you can implement that:

```
QProgressDialog *progress = new QProgressDialog();
progress->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
progress->setWindowTitle("Stimulated Movement");
progress->setLabelText("Please wait for a moment while the motor is moving!");
progress->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
progress->setModal(true);
progress->setRange(0, 0);
QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Terminate");
progress->setCancelButton(b);

progress->show();
//move it to the center of progress after you show it
//y coordinate stays the same, and you have to calculate x relatively to the button and dialog width 
b->move((progress->width()-b->width())/2,b->geometry().y());
```

However there is a problem with this method, the button will not stay in the center if the dialog is resized.

Fixing that, needs `resizeEvent` reimplementation, but if you don't need resizing, you might just want to set a fixed size for the dialog to prevent it.

For example:

```
progress->setFixedSize(310,100);
```